# WCF: The socket connection was aborted. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, entity-framework-4

```
public class MyClass1
{
   public string name;
   ...
}

public class MyClass2 
{ 
   public string address;
   ...
}

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ServName" maxReceivedMessageSize="20971520" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"/>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceName
{
   [OperationContract]
   List<MyClass2> GetMyClass2List();
}
```

I have two basic entity classes, as per above, **when I call a method(GetMyClass2List) to load MyClass2 it works fine**.

```
public class MyClass2 : MyClass1
{...}
```

But when I change MyClass2 to reference MyClass1, all of the sudden the same method(GetMyClass2List) that I used to load MyClass2 doesn't work. 
gives the error: ***The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:59.9978180'***

***An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host***

Am I missing something?

Comment: You need to provide details for your WCF-Service you're using, we can't guess what's wrong without having any hints. Are you using any sockets in your class? Might also be the problem, but could be a WCF-Service, as you've added the WCF tag...

Comment: @ElGauchooo what details would you like me to add?

Comment: How about some details of your implementation? I just see two classes - no implementation detail at all..

Comment: Add your ServiceContract, too.